Incompatible types. Found: 'org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value', required: 'int'
I am working with springboot and trying to create a table and some of its column based on some configuration like the column trx_amount should be of type bigDecimal with precision and scale based on the configuration in application-properties.
by the way precision and scale should be of type int.
@Entity
@Table(name = "transactions")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Transactions{
  @Column(name = "trx_amount",precision = @Value("${transaction-amount-digits}") , scale = @Value("#{new Long('${transaction-amount-fractions}')}")))
   private BigDecimal amount;

  ..


}

I am getting the below error compile error
 Incompatible types. Found: 'org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value', required: 'int'



Don't post code as images. Use code tags when doing so. You cannot use @Value in JPA annotations. So this isn't going to work (and no it never will as Hibernate doesn't know anything about @Value or how to process them and Spring doesn't about @Column nor does it care, next to that values in annotations have to be constants or processing expression have to be build in the annotation processors).

The @Column annotation parameters (precision and scale) are not designed to accept dynamic values injected via @Value. The @Value annotation does support SpEL, but it cannot be used directly within JPA annotations like @Column.
